# ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key error with weblogic

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl

I am using weblogic 10.3.6 and have one admin and 4 managed servers configured. On one of the managed server listening on SSL port 7299, one way SSL has been enabled with a certificate with key size 2048.
    When I am trying to access applications deployed on SSL enabled managed server using Internet explorer 9, I am able to open the home page of application on SSL port but as soon as I press any button on GUI of the application it logs me out.

```
If I access same application on SSL port using Firefox 38.3.0, It shows the following error on browser

Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key" or ERR_SSL_WEAK_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY
If you see this error, it means that a secure connection can't be established because of outdated security code on the website. Chrome protects your privacy by preventing you from connecting to these sites. You won't be able to visit this page using Chrome.
If you're a website administrator, we recommend you update your server to support ECDHE and disable DHE. If ECDHE is unavailable, you can instead disable all DHE cipher suites and rely on plain RSA.


Later I got some options that weakens the mozilla firefox security as below.

security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha
security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha 

But after setting these variables false in firefox, my applications navigations are fine and works well.


I would add that when the https logs were captured using fiddler, I got to know the below

Client side ciphers available
Ciphers: 
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C007]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C011]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5



and the below are the server side ciphers

server side ciphers available



 <DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure] 28 cipher suites enabled:>
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5>
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA>
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA>
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA>
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA>
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA>
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA>
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA>
<SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA>
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA>
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA>
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA>
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA>
TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA>
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA>
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA>
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA>
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA>
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5>
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5>
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA>
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA>
SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA>
TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA>
SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA>
TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA>
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV>


There was one solution available on google, to replace the localPolicy.jar and US_export_Policy.jar in JDK with the unlimited encryption version. Although I tried the same, but still the same error persist.

Could you please suggest any fix on weblogic10.3.6 server for the same issue or any setting in IE 9.  

I got the following solutions in the above post.
•Deploy ECDHE Cipher Suites
 •Disable Export Cipher Suites

I am not sure how to do this in weblogic, can you please suggest.

Early response is highly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have MOS, then check out this document...Doc ID 1936300.1

You have to be using at least one of these minimum java versions or higher...

If using jRockit, update your jRockit version to minimum 1.6.0_101 
If using Oracle Java 6, update your Java 6 to minimum 1.6.0_101 
If using Oracle Java 7, update your Java 7 to minimum 1.7.0_85

You must be using at least this minimum Weblogic server version...

WLS 10.3.6.0.12

Weblogic must be utilizing the jsse ssl implementation to use the latest tsl versions and to disable old ssl versions (sslv2 and sslv3 versions)

Once both of those have been updated(if needed), you need to configure the JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable. This will disable the old ssl versions and only allow TLS1 and higher...

export JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=TLS1

That will resolve the issue with updated firefox and chrome browsers displaying an error "Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key" when you navigate to the site. I did not have any issues with IE but we've upgraded to a later IE version than IE9. This will pass the poodle/diffie-hellman vulnerability check. I am still trying to figure out how to implement a stronger 2048bit instead of 1028bit diffie-hellman group with weblogic, but the fix above will at least get rid of the error and allow access to the site.

Comment: Hi Ameeks,    After upgrading to jdk 8 with weblogic10.3.6, the problem of ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key error has been resolved in Google Chrome and Firefox also. Thanks for that . But in the below version of IE  8.0.7601.17514
9.0.8112
9.0.8112
11.0.9600
This fix is not working and the application is still logging out. I tried changing the SSL versions to TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 in Internet explorer setting  ---> Advanced --> Security Section. Could you please suggest any fix or setting in IE that I would have missed.

Comment: Hi Ameeks,    After upgrading to jdk 8 with weblogic10.3.6, the problem of ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key error has been resolved in Google Chrome and Firefox also. Thanks for that . But in the below version of IE  8.0.7601.17514
9.0.8112
9.0.8112
11.0.9600
This fix is not working and the application is still logging out. I tried changing the SSL versions to TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 in Internet explorer setting  ---> Advanced --> Security Section. Could you please suggest any fix or setting in IE that I would have missed.